# How to improve this nested for loop using GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'd like to learn an alternative way to run this for loop, because currently, it sets the value through each iteration and as this can get large, it better be more performant.

```
function calculate() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const settingSheet = ss.getSheetByName('settings'); 
const dataSheet= ss.getSheetByName('Data'); 

let settingData = settingSheet.getRange(1, 1, settingSheet.getLastRow(), settingSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
let spcData = dataSheet.getRange(1, 1, dataSheet.getLastRow(), dataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

let recordTypesAccepted = ['strategy1', 'goal2'];

var settingPar1 = settingData.filter(e => e[0] == 'default').map(e => e[1]);
var settingPar2 = settingData.filter(e => e[0] == 'default').map(e => e[2]);

for (let a = 0; a < spcData.length; a++) {
  for (let r = 0; r < settingData .length; r++) {

      let settingSearchTerm = settingData[r][4];
      let spcSearchTerm = spcData[a][10];

      let settingMatchType = settingData[r][5];
      let spcMatchType = spcData[a][9];

      let spcRecordType = spcData[a][8];

      if (recordTypesAccepted.indexOf(spcRecordType) > -1 && settingMatchType === spcMatchType) {
        if (settingSearchTerm == spcSearchTerm) {
          settingPar1 = settingData[r][7];
          settingPar2 = settingData[r][6];
        }

        let spcClicks = spcData[a][10];
        let spcOrders = spcData[a][11];

        let row = a + 1;

        if (spcClicks >= settingsPar1 && spcOrders >= settingsPar2) {
          let newValue = 10;
          spcSheet.getRange(row, 20).setValue(newBid).setBackground("#D8E271");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you just store the results and backgrounds in a seperate array, then when the loop is finished put the values and backgrounds in column 20?  As long as there are no formulas in column 20.

Comment: I've thought of it, @TheWizEd, but I'm not sure how to store the index so that the background and formatting can be applied ... thanks.

Comment: You only `setBackground`, anything else?

Comment: In your code you don't define `spcSheet`, I'm assuming its is defined elsewhere?

Comment: ```spcSheet``` is defined elsewhere. Not in this example though. Sorry about that. ```setNumberFormat(€##0.00).setBackround("green")``` thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Description**

Provided using setValues() doesn't overwrite any formulas you could use getValues() to get an array of the old values, replace any that need to be updated and simply put back the array of values using setValues().  The same for back grounds and number formats.

Note it is assumed from the OP that `spcSheet` is defined elsewhere.

**Script**

```
function calculate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const settingSheet = ss.getSheetByName('settings'); 
  const dataSheet= ss.getSheetByName('Data'); 

  let settingData = settingSheet.getRange(1, 1, settingSheet.getLastRow(), settingSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let spcData = dataSheet.getRange(1, 1, dataSheet.getLastRow(), dataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  let recordTypesAccepted = ['strategy1', 'goal2'];

  var settingPar1 = settingData.filter(e => e[0] == 'default').map(e => e[1]);
  var settingPar2 = settingData.filter(e => e[0] == 'default').map(e => e[2]);

  let spcRange = spcSheet.getRange(1,20,spcSheet.getLastRow(),1)
  var spcValues = spcRange.getValues();
  var backgrounds = spcRange.getBackgrounds();
  var numberformats = spcRange.getNumberFormats();

  for (let a = 0; a < spcData.length; a++) {
    for (let r = 0; r < settingData .length; r++) {

      let settingSearchTerm = settingData[r][4];
      let spcSearchTerm = spcData[a][10];

      let settingMatchType = settingData[r][5];
      let spcMatchType = spcData[a][9];

      let spcRecordType = spcData[a][8];

      if (recordTypesAccepted.indexOf(spcRecordType) > -1 && settingMatchType === spcMatchType) {
        if (settingSearchTerm == spcSearchTerm) {
          settingPar1 = settingData[r][7];
          settingPar2 = settingData[r][6];
        }

        let spcClicks = spcData[a][10];
        let spcOrders = spcData[a][11];

        if (spcClicks >= settingsPar1 && spcOrders >= settingsPar2) {
          let newValue = 10;
          spcValues[a][0] = newBid;
          backgrounds[a][0] = "#D8E271";
          numberformats[a][0] = "€##0.00";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  spcRange.setValues(spcValues);
  spcRange.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
  spcRange.setNumberFormats(numberformats);
}
```

**Reference**

- [Range.getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getBackgrounds())
- [Range.setBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackgrounds(String))
- [Range.getNumberFormats()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumberformats)
- [Range.setNumberFormats()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatsnumberformats)

Comment: Thank you. Just to make sure I get it: By declaring ```spcValues```, for example, and assinging iterated values to it as criteria is met, it gets "populated"?

Comment: It was already populated with the existing values when I `var spcValues = spcRange.getValues();`.  Then I replace the existing value in that array with a new value when the criteria is met with `spcValues[a][0] = newBid;`.

Comment: So many gaps here in my mind, concept wise. My real situation has many more criteria and situations and this approach DID work! Thank you!